# Mysql query find substring

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I have a table like this:

```
country (id, name)
```

I want to find the id where for example the search string is "Russian Federation" and in my table is stored the value "Russia".

Pratically the stored value is a substring of the search string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Country
  WHERE 'Russian Federation' LIKE CONCAT('%', Name, '%')
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfb49/1) Demo.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the case, then you can do:

```
select *
from country
where concat(' ', SEARCHSTRING, ' ') like concat('% ', name, ' %')
```

Or you can use `find_in_set()`:

```
select *
from country
where find_in_set(name, replace(SEARCHSTRING, ' ', ',')) > 0;
```

Comment: using find_in_set function it seem that doesn't works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfb49/13/0